# VBA - Go through Worksheets and end with one sheet with found strings, from all Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I can't get this code to work. I am trying to go through all worksheets in a Excel Book, And when I find a row that contains "Syst" it is supposed to pop up in a list in the worksheet "Systemoversikt"

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()
MsgBox "Testing"
Dim WS_Count As Integer, j As Integer
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

' Begin the loop.
For j = 1 To WS_Count
    Dim sh  As Worksheet
    Dim i   As Long
    Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(j)
    sh.Activate
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim n   As Integer
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        n = 3
        Dim systemnummer As String
        systemnummer = Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, [4])

        If systemnummer = "Syst" Then
            Sheets("Systemoversikt").Cells(n, 8).Value = Cells(i, n).Value
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: What's not working? Is there an error? Also, I'm pretty sure you don't need the `[]` around `[4]` in the `LEFT()` formula.

Comment: Right now your code only adds a single cell's value to the Systemoversikt worksheet. Do you want to add the entire row to the worksheet?

Comment: Also it seems like you are traversing your sheet diagonally by incrementing n and i within the same for loop. Could you put up a screenshot of a sample worksheet's data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your search and loop method needs improvement. Here's a simplified version. It's not as fast and efficient as using a find function, but I think it gets you what you need.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

Dim SearchWkb As Workbook
Dim DestWkb As Workbook
Set SearchWkb = ActiveWorkbook
Set DestWkb = Workbooks("Punktliste11.xlsm") 'updated!


'Begin loop through sheets
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim vCell As Range
For Each sh In SearchWkb.Sheets
    If sh.Name <> "Systemoversikt" Then

    'Look through all activerange cells (this could be done faster but good for illustration)
    For Each vCell In sh.UsedRange.Cells

        If Left(vCell.Value, 4) = "Syst" Then
        DestWkb.Sheets("Systemoversikt").Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = vCell.Value
        End If

    Next vCell
    End If
Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: THANKS :D, hmm. When I use the name of the excel fil like:  Set SearchWkb = "Punktliste11.xlsm"
Set DestWkb = "Punktliste11.xlsm"            I get Type mismatch.

Comment: Sorry @LaraHammer , my fault. I'll update answer in 1 minute with correction (hazards of writing code in commented out form)

Comment: thank u so much for the help! Its not working. Im supposed to get all the numers in rows, in column 1 in systemoversikt. I am searching in the workbook Punktliste11, and I want all the numbers in sheet systemoversikt that is a sheet in the workbook Punktliste11, so i have the same search workbook as Search workbook.  It makes sence? It actually seems like the code from u doesnt even search through any workbooks. and i really dont understand how to modify it either since I maybe think u misunderstood my problem maybe? I dont know :(

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't really make sense to me. I understand everything is in the same workbook, so you can set that in the code. After that, your language becomes a little tough to comprehend. Perhaps post some illustrative examples?

Comment: I GOT IT TO WORK!! :D with small modification of your code. thanks